# Add class when scroll down with AlloyUI

Tags: jquery, css, alloy-ui

I need to add a class when the user scroll down. I usually do this *with jQuery*:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 10) {
    $(".dockbar").addClass("dockbar-opacity");
  }
});
```

How can I do the same thing **with AlloyUI**?
Really thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [ScrollInfo plugin](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/Plugin.ScrollInfo.html) and its [`scroll` event](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/Plugin.ScrollInfo.html#event_scroll)

```
var body = Y.one('body');

body.plug(Y.Plugin.ScrollInfo);

body.scrollInfo.on('scroll', function (e) {
    if (e.scrollTop >= 10){
       Y.one('.dockbar').addClass('dockbar-opacity');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the speed to respond. I'll try your advice. Working with AlloyUI and Liferay. After I tell if it has worked.

Comment: "Merci" Gaby, you rules ;-)