# Menu sticky conversion from jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, liferay-aui, alloy-ui

In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217479/add-class-when-scroll-down-with-alloyui/31641489#31641489), a user asked how to convert a jQuery script to AUI.

Unfortunately, the answer didn't work for me.

#### My Objective

To get the menu to stick when the menu element is leaving the window viewport.

#### the jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 40) {
        $('#navigation').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('#navigation').removeClass('stick');
    }
});
```

#### My Alloy Attempt

```
    AUI().use('aui-node', function(Y) {
    var node = Y.one('#navigation');
    var body = Y.one('body');
    body.plug(Y.Plugin.ScrollInfo); 
    if (e.scrollTop >= 10){
        node.addClass('stick');
    } else {
        node.removeClasse('stick');
    }
});
```

This results in the error 'cannot read property "on (not using 'scroll' as that caused another error, 'mousewheel' works in a different variant)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems to be missing the line: `body.scrollInfo.on('scroll', function (e) {` from [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217479/add-class-when-scroll-down-with-alloyui/31641489#31641489).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the [`node-scroll-info` module](http://alloyui.com/api/modules/node-scroll-info.html) and listen to [`scrollInfo`'s `scroll` event](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/Plugin.ScrollInfo.html#event_scroll):

```
YUI().use('aui-node', 'node-scroll-info', function (Y) {
    var node = Y.one('#navigation');
    var body = Y.one('body');
    body.plug(Y.Plugin.ScrollInfo);
    body.scrollInfo.on('scroll', function (e) {
        if (e.scrollTop >= 10) {
            node.addClass('stick');
        } else {
            node.removeClasse('stick');
        }
    });
});
```